# How to add a hover effect with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm working on this site http://wiafe.github.io/Love-Nonprofits/index.html and near the bottom there are divs that hold messages. And I would like to add an hover effect that will display two buttons and a link over it. And everything I have tried has failed so checking to see if there is a way to do it. I took out the html portions I had and kept the css classes. Have been messing with it all day and it's breaking my brain right now.

HTML:

```
<div class="message">
    <a class="message-content overlay">I<span class="heart"></span>working for a nonprofit because we care about more than our own cause. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam,<br><span class="signature">Leaslie S.</span>

    </a>

    <a class="message-content overlay">I<span class="heart"></span>working for a nonprofit because we care about more than our own cause. <br><span class="signature">Leaslie S.</span>

    </a>    

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.message-content:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.message-content p {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  background: black;
  background: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
  transition: height .5s;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s;
  -moz-transition: height .5s;
}

.message-content:hover small {
  opacity: 0;
}

.message-content:hover .show-description p {
  height: 100%;
}

.message-content .show-description small {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.message-content').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('show-description');
});
```

Comment: have you taken the time to google it? this link shows you exactly how its done .. http://jsfiddle.net/6zfQN/ this will help if you hover over hyperlink 2 you can see it working how you want. hope it helps.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: A lot of them are for images, which I still have tried and doesn't work for whatever reason.

Comment: ive just gave you a working jsfiddle which has all the code in? what dont you know now? @user3922686

Comment: Maybe I worded it wrong, but I made a codepen, so in the codepen I want box-2 to cover box-1 when box-1 is hovered. It's basically the same approach in which I'll take with this page. @JoshStevens http://codepen.io/wiafe/details/GJrZjG/

Comment: Here is a javascript solution I made in supplement to the already provided css fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/6zfQN/309/

Comment: You could do this without JS, it should be simple

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS:

```
.box > .appear {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.box:hover > .appear {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Add class `.appear` to whatever you want to display on hover over `.box`.

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/pn1qw223/1/)